# C open() sycall returns -1 for a variable path parameter

Tags: c

Trying to open a file using open(). Returns the correct file descriptor when we call it like so:

```
fd = open("a.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

But when we use a token generated from strtok(), it returns -1:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
fd = open(token, O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the token to see that it is what you expect?

Comment: yes, using `printf("File: %s\n", token);` we get the output `File: a.txt` @John3136. As for the question, we were wondering if there was something we were messing up we weren't aware of.

Comment: The call is failing so use `perror` (or similar) to find out *why* it is failing.

Comment: Yes, check `errno` as suggested above, and also make sure that the token is really only `"a.txt"`, and doesn't have any whitespace or non-printable characters that you are not seeing from the `printf`. (My guess would be that it has a linefeed at the end.)

Comment: @Arkku was right it had a carriage return and newline at the end of it. The problem was that it was in response to a "GET a.txt" message to a server (for a class), didn't account for the newline whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctly guessed in comments: `token` is not actually the same string as `"a.txt"`, but contains extra whitespace at the end, which makes it hard to see when printed as a string.